# Alsa is just not working right or I dont know

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I've been using linux for 5 years now but this is new for me...

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
python: src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:3636: PaAlsaStreamComponent_BeginPolling: Assertion `ret == self->nfds' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I can use my mic in the system like recording stuff with it and even talk in voice chat with no problem but when I try to run my speech recognition program its just fails like this...

Answer (score 3):

this seems to be a known issue with `portaudio` where ALSA (Linux's low-level sound API) returns an error in an unexpected place

this seems to be a known issue (e.g. see [here](https://app.assembla.com/spaces/portaudio/tickets/268/details)) but the authors seem to have issues with the code, and it never got added to the package

I've just stumbled on the same issue and am trying again with code that will hopefully address their issues with the previous patches

not sure if/when it would show up in Ubuntu though

Comment: Not sure what to make of that bug report actually. Getting the same error on Ubuntu 18.04 (`src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:3636: PaAlsaStreamComponent_BeginPolling: Assertion `ret == self->nfds' failed`)

Comment: I think an evolved version of this patch (or just one solving this issue for me) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60824906/1509695. You also have some instructions for how to build and install it for Ubuntu there.

Comment: Can't seem to have permission to comment on the issue in PortAudio's Assembla, hope there'll be an official fix on its trunk.